# Merge 10 lines of code into 1

Tags: vba, excel

I have written some code that works, but slowly.

Can someone please help me merge these ten lines of ugly code into one elegant line?:

```
    Worksheets(Cells(x, "P").Value).Cells(Cells(x, "Q").Value, "A").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Worksheets(Cells(x, "P").Value).Cells(Cells(x, "Q").Value, "B").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Worksheets(Cells(x, "P").Value).Cells(Cells(x, "Q").Value, "C").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Worksheets(Cells(x, "P").Value).Cells(Cells(x, "Q").Value, "D").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Worksheets(Cells(x, "P").Value).Cells(Cells(x, "Q").Value, "E").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Worksheets(Cells(x, "P").Value).Cells(Cells(x, "Q").Value, "F").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Worksheets(Cells(x, "P").Value).Cells(Cells(x, "Q").Value, "G").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Worksheets(Cells(x, "P").Value).Cells(Cells(x, "Q").Value, "H").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Worksheets(Cells(x, "P").Value).Cells(Cells(x, "Q").Value, "I").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Worksheets(Cells(x, "P").Value).Cells(Cells(x, "Q").Value, "J").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps

```
Worksheets(Cells(x, "P").Value).Cells(Cells(x, "Q").Value, "A").Resize(, 10).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```